# Вставить строку в другую строку по позиции

Tags: php

Есть строка типа `1ef75b369804f887a0f1a3efa39f0d12.jpg`. Как вставить в 32 позицию слово `_thumb` что бы получилось `1ef75b369804f887a0f1a3efa39f0d12_thumb.jpg` на php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$oldStr = "1ef75b369804f887a0f1a3efa39f0d12.jpg";
$str_to_insert = "_thumb";
$pos = 32;
$newstr = substr_replace($oldstr, $str_to_insert, $pos, 0);
```

[Ссылка на документацию](http://php.net/substr_replace)